# Tab bar disappears when linking back to it

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode9

I have an APP I am building that has a number of different view controllers from standard ones to pageView and tabBarView Controllers. My problem is that the TabBar works perfect going from it, but when I link a button back from to the page that has the tabBar the tabBar no longer shows. Can someone tell me why this happens and possible how to fix this issue.

Here is my Segue set-up for the boards in question:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in image 1 there Tour Selection has a tabBar, and after the segue in image 2 the tabBar is gone, as it is when I run the app.

I am largely building this app in storyboard for all the stuff that does not require logic, like the info boards.

Comment: Don't segue back, dismiss the view you segued to instead.

Comment: hmmmm, ok, how would I best go about that, still new to programming. Learning day by day :-D help by help

Comment: Worked it out thanks, but can you add it as an answer so I can tick it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments as requested by the post author:

> Don't segue back, dismiss the view you segued to instead